# I want these functions to be accessible to every js controller throughout my application. How do I achieve this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few functions that do redirection on angularjs:

```
$scope.a= function()
{
    $location.url('/a');
    return;
}
$scope.b= function()
{
    $location.url('/b');
    return;
}
$scope.c = function()
{
    $location.url('/c');
    return;
}
$scope.d= function()
{
    $location.url('/d');
    return;
}
$scope.e= function()
{
    $location.url('/e');
    return;
}
$scope.f= function()
{
    $location.url('/f');
    return;
}
```

These have been declared inside one controller but I want every other js controller to have access to it. I want to avoid having to copy and paste these functions in every other controller. How do I achieve this?

angular routes:

```
 var hot_keys =  [
        ['. p','a','RedirectService.a()'],
        ['. o','b','RedirectService.b()'],
        ['. i','c','RedirectService.c()'],
        ['. f','d','RedirectService.d()'],
        ['. v','e','RedirectService.e()'],
        ['. a','f','RedirectService.f()']
    ];

 .when('/a', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/a',
         controller: 'aController',
         hotkeys: hot_keys
     })
```

what this does is if user presses ". a" it should call the RedirectService.a();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Service and reuse it wherever you want

Service

```
 var App = angular.module('App', []);
    App.service(function ($location) {
        return {
            a: function () {
                $location.url('/a'); return;
            },
            b: function () {
                $location.url('/b'); return;
            },
            c: function () {
                $location.url('/c'); return;
            },
            d: function () {
                $location.url('/d'); return;
            },
            e: function () {
                $location.url('/e'); return;
            },
            f: function () {
                $location.url('/f'); return;
            }
        };
    });
```

How to use in a controller

```
App.controller(function($scope, RedirectService){
  // call function a
   RedirectService.a();    
});
```

Comment: Did this and it works if I do it this way, but I'm binding these inside my angular routes. Refer to my question in 2 minutes. I'll update.

Comment: @user3278616 I'm not sure what is hotkeys, If you send link to documentation I would probably be able to help

Comment: https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/

Basically, i'm binding them inside my angular routes. If there's a way to call the function inside the angular routes using the service, it would work brilliantly.

instead of `['. p', 'a', 'a()']`

Can I use something like `['. p', 'a', 'RedirectService.a()']` ?

So far it's not working, but if there's a way to call the service from the angular routes, it would be amazing.

Comment: Problem is that once I refresh, everything is unbinded (obviously) but if there was a way to call the function using service, it wouldn't be a problem. I'd just include the service inside every controller I need to use it in aside from creating a function inside every controller that uses the service.

Comment: @user3278616 I think I see what you mean, instead of `['. p', 'a', 'RedirectService.a()']` Do `['. p', 'a', 'redirect.a()']` Then in every controller you just need to inject RedirectService and also define `$scope.redirect = RedirectService;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `redirectService` and inject him the `$location`.
He will do the redirecting.
Inject the `redirectService` to the controllers who need it.

If you need them on your **scope** then you can:

1.Add them to the `rootScope`.
2.Use controller inheritance(e.g. each controller who needs them will inherit a base contoller).
Read [here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Please make all the scope functions to rootScope functions. Please check the below code.

```
$rootScope.a= function()
{
    $location.url('/a');
    return;
}
$rootScope.b= function()
{
    $location.url('/b');
    return;
}
$rootScope.c = function()
{
    $location.url('/c');
    return;
}
$scope.d= function()
{
    $location.url('/d');
    return;
}
$rootScope.e= function()
{
    $location.url('/e');
    return;
}
$rootScope.f= function()
{
    $location.url('/f');
    return;
}
```

Comment: after making them into $rootScope functions, how do I declare them inside my other controllers?

Comment: This is a bad approach, $rootScope is not made for such use, Use a service

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) which can contain these functions with $location injected into it.
And this service can be injected into the controllers where you need it.

Another solution would be to use ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to route to different states rather than specific urls.